# Vector drawable in any location within text view (not outside of it)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textview

Is there a way to add a drawable in any position within a text view programmatically without having to position it on a particular side of a text view? The following code works when using unicode character but I want to try the same with a vector drawable.

```
textView.text = getString(R.string.app_settings) + " \u2794 " + getString(R.string.display)
```

[image]

Comment: Try `ImageSpan` or `DynamicDrawableSpan`, then add the span to your text.

Comment: How can it be scaled to match the text size?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. However, based on your diagram, your requirement isn't "add a drawable in any position within a text view". It is "add a drawable in lieu of a character". To do that, you need some form of `CharacterStyle`, such as the `ImageSpan` and `DynamicDrawableSpan` that I suggested.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have a vector drawable which looks the same as the character. Do you mean an `ImageSpan` inside a `SpannableString`?

Comment: "Do you mean an ImageSpan inside a SpannableString?" -- yes. Sorry, I should have been more clear in my original comment. You would set up some form of `Spanned` that has your text plus the `ImageSpan`, then put that `Spanned` in the `TextView`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For me, ImageSpan works.
You can put a delimiter and replace it with the drawable. I used a google icon in this example

[image: Demo]:

**Code with delimiter replacement:**

```
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.google_icon);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 100,100);

    String text = " Google %google_icon% icon";
    String delimiter = "%google_icon%";
    
    int icon_index = text.indexOf("%google_icon%");
    text = text.replace(delimiter," ");
    
    Spannable span = new SpannableString(text);
    ImageSpan image = new ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    span.setSpan(image, icon_index, icon_index+1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    
    textView.setText(span);
```

Or, you can place the drawable on any index like:

```
span.setSpan(image, start_index, end_index, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

PS: I used Display1 in text appearance. You need to change drawable bounds according to your own needs.

Comment: In a fragment, what does `this` in `ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.google_icon);` need to change to?

Comment: "this" can mostly be replaced by "getApplicationContext()". If your using a fragment, you can use "view.getContext()" in method "onViewCreated"

Comment: This only works when I add a question mark after `drawable`. This doesn't seem to work when I try to use the `google_icon` image more than once. How can I use "Google G icon" on another line within the same span?

Comment: `drawable` in `val image = ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)` gives this warning: `Required: Drawable, Found: Drawable?`

Comment: MacaronLover, Its working for me. To adjust the span, you can write a code to adjust the size accordingly. I didn't get the Drawable? problem. I sent a screenshot of working program. Please attach you code, I'll try to fix it

Comment: If this is not helpful, I can delete the answer

Comment: Hi, this now works for me. Could you also provide an example of how to use the icon more than once please? For example: "Google, G symbol, icon, G symbol, Google"

Comment: Do you want to use multiple icons in single line?

Comment: Yes, i.e. Text (Google), Drawable (G symbol), Text (icon), Drawable (G symbol), Text (Google), Drawable (G symbol), Text (services)